# How to send location with whatsapp web js

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots, whatsapp

can you help me to send the location of a place with Whatsapp web js
Like I want to send a user who messages me location then the location would be sent of London or any other place.
ThankYou
Here are the Whatsapp web js docs https://github.com/pedroslopez/whatsapp-web.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to create a location and send as message.

```
const location = new Location(latitude, longitude, description of location);
client.sendMessage(user, location);
```